# Почему переменная el выводит значение 4?

Tags: python, list

Я ведь присваиваю переменной `el` элемент из списка под индексом 4. Под индексом 4 расположена цифра 3, но выводит в всё равно цифру 4

Код:

```py
l = list(range(5))

el = l[4]

print(l)
print(el)
```

Вывод:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
4
```

Comment: А всего то надо было попробовать брать элементы с разными индексами, и вы бы быстро сами во всём разобрались.

Comment: Под индексом 4 находится значение 4, так как индексы начинаются с 0.

Answer (score 7):

Индексы начинаются с 0, поэтому элемент с индексом 4 - последний в списке из 5 элементов.